# How to interpret predictions from a specific PyTorch Model

Tags: python, pytorch, prediction

I have obtained the prediction values from this [PyTorch model](https://github.com/allegro/allRank/issues/55), at least I think so(https://github.com/allegro/allRank) by running:

`slates_X, slates_y = __rank_slates(val_dl, model)`

But the output shape is not clear to me. The number of rows in `slates_y` is corresponds with the number of `qids` in my dataset. But I would imagine it should match the number of rows instead, since I want the predicted rank of each row.

Does anyone know or understand, how I can get the predictions for each observation?

I have tried this with rank_slates instead (which is just a wrapper around `__rank_slates` and then get the same result.